# Workflow of Collaboration on wordpress development

Tags: theme-development, database, sync

We, two developers, are developing a wordpress website from scratch. We are using git but it does not allow us to push,pull and merge the database. In this circumstance what is the best workflow?
We have explored sync-db but that completely replaces an existing database what we don't want to be happened. There is a plugin named margebot but that is way too much pricey for our project. What we can do to collaborate on this project ?

Comment: why would you want to version a database??

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, only the site users should make modifications to the DB. As a developers, if the is some part of the DB that should be changed, you should write the changes in code. Maybe do some "upgrade" type of function which synchronizes DB structure to what the current code expects, and remove it before going 1.0.